# Need connect myC# application with Azure SQL. Help me please

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, visual-studio-code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;

public static class Helper
    {
        public static string GetConnectionString(string name)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
```

I use Visual Code that works not so good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Menu" connectionString="" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I think, maybe there is mistake in connection string? I use Azure Connection String ADO SQL, but maybe I miss something in my code. because I investigate this problem too long. I am fresher so any help will be useful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class DataAccess : IGetMenue
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public DataAccess(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<Dish> GetMenu()
    {
        List<Dish> menu = new List<Dish>();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM Menu";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Dish menuItem = new Dish();
                    menuItem.DishID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MenuID"]);
                    menuItem.DishName = Convert.ToString(reader["MenuName"]);
                    menuItem.Price = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Price"]);
                    menuItem.DishDescription = Convert.ToString(reader["MenuDescription"]);
                    menuItem.PrepareTime = Convert.ToInt32(reader["PrepareTime"]);
                    menu.Add(menuItem);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            // Handle the exception, log it, or rethrow it as needed.
        }

        return menu;
    }
}
```

here I tried connect my tables from SQL to my application. But it returns null

Comment: Have you debugged and at least verified that you can connect? How are you calling `DataAccess GetMenu()`?

Comment: Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: I have such a comment when I start my app